# Monitor USB hub's unusual and faulty behavior with a USB flash drive

Tags: usb, display, cable, usb-3, usb-hub

Typical USB3-A (PC) to USB3-B (Monitor) upstream port setup, in my case using (intentionally) a 5m long (USB3) cable.

I can connect mouse or keyboard and it works just fine, but when I try 128GB USB3 flash key, nothing happens, as if it were not even there. I tried all 4 ports on the monitor, same result.

**However**, if I unplug the upstream port and plug it right back, while having the flash key connected, it will get recognized right away and works as expected.

Monitor is EIZO EV2760 and I have updated Intel® USB 3.0 eXtensible Host Controller Driver.

I suspect it might be the cable's length (I don't have shorter one to test), but why does it work when re-plugging the upstream cable?

(according to specs from the manual, a supply current for individual port is max. 900 mA)

**UPDATE:** It **is** working if I connect the upstream cable to USB 2 port on my PC! It's just the USB 3 ports (I tried three of them) where this issue appears.

Answer (score 0):

On reconnect of a USB-Hub the hub iterates through the plugged-in devices in series to ensure detection and prevent overload. This is not the case though when devices are already attached and the hub already initialized/is in use. In the latter case:

1. The initial power-draw of the USB3-flash-drive might be too high (which is unlikely but can happen although it should be prevented due to the hard-cap of the hub/controller for each port, as well as the overall hardcap).
2. The voltage-drop/resistance might be too stark - this can happen when:

- the ground-contact is saturated (by being linked to the ground of the display-components)
- the ground-contact of the plugs is not sufficient
- the shielding of the cable is broken or not linked in its entirety

Replacing the cable between Hub and PC "might" help.

Comment: Thanks for the comment. Today I actually found the cable supplied with the monitor, which is only 2m long, but it (usb hub) behaves exactly the same. I tried two different USB 3 Patriot flash drives. I wonder, if it's not a driver issue, if I should apply warranty.

Comment: Well, I found out some other detail. I tried all six rear USB3 ports with the supplied 2m upstream A-B cable. None of them worked, but my two USB3 (connected to additional USB3 header on the motherboard) frontpanel ports seem to be working. I don't know what makes the difference. However if I use the 5m cable, not even frontpanel USB3 ports will work.

Comment: Sorry, but the only workaround i can think of is buying an active USB3.1 card for a 1x/2x/4x PCIe-slot which couples directly to the Power-Supply and allows for example quick-charging when the PC is in standby. This way you can circumvent the likely possible problem that the motherboard unintellegently prevents the re-initialization due to a sudden power-surge when connecting the Patriot-drives. There are lots of possibilities to investigate/probe by updating firmware for the drives, the onboard-USB-hub, etc., but if you have never done that it will be a pain, this i can guarantee you as well.

Comment: Yes i though of that, but an USB extension card is overkill for my use case. Since the last time I have tried couple of more cables with different gauge, no change. Like suggested, it is most likely a specific problem with the way my motherboard handles it, or perhaps the driver issue, or both. I connected the 5m cable to monitor and USB3 port on some random laptop I had at home and the hub worked as expected.

Comment: I am gonna try to use "USB 3.0 Cable Dual Power Cable" and see if it helps. This sort of cable costs only couple of bucks and is designed to provide some additional power for the USB port.

Comment: Alright, the cheap "dual power" cable made no difference, so I'm inclined to think it's some combination of hardware and driver incompatibility. My two USB3-flash-drives simply won't work. Interestingly though, I connected my smartphone and tablet to the hub and both worked ok. So, I'm resting my case..